# c++ WinAPI Layered Window, children do not paint

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am currently working on a project, where i need to create transparent bubble as main body. To make this transparence i used WS_EX_LAYERED on window creation. But now, i can't get children to render, but they do exist and even function like they should, they are just not visible. Without Layered Window mode everything renders just fine. What is wrong?

Here is my window creation:

```
winClass = {};
winClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
winClass.hInstance = hInstance;
winClass.hIcon = hIcon;
winClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
winClass.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
winClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)0;

winClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
winClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
winClass.cbWndExtra = 0;

RegisterClass(&winClass);

Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiinput = {};
gdiinput.GdiplusVersion = 1;

Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupOutput gdioutput = {};
Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&WinGDIToken, &gdiinput, &gdioutput);

hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED,
    CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
    L"Color Picker",    // Window text
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,            // Window style

    // Size and position
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 700 * Scale, 516 * Scale,

    NULL,       // Parent window    
    NULL,       // Menu
    hInstance,  // Instance handle
    NULL        // Additional application data
);

Window::PopulateClientWithWindows(hWnd);
```

And here is PopulateClientWithWindows(hwnd) func:

```
    void Window::PopulateClientWithWindows(HWND hwnd)
    {
        HWND test = CreateWindow(L"edit", L"Test ", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 50, 50, 
        100, 100, hwnd, NULL, hI, NULL);
   }
```

Comment: [Layered windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows) are not compatible with standard Win32 controls. Layered windows are drawn from bitmaps only. To update a layered window, you have to draw its content into a bitmap and call `UpdateLayeredWindow()`. Regular controls typically respond to `WM_PAINT` to draw into a screen device context instead and know nothing about the bitmap _you_ provide to `UpdateLayeredWindow()`.

Comment: But what can i do then? I have an idea, i can make my own controls, or use win32 controls for logic, and gdi+ to draw their appearance. What would be the best practice?

Comment: The required SetLayeredWindowAttributes() call is missing.  Use LWA_COLORKEY to create a window with a transparent background.  But keep in mind that text needs a well-defined background color to look good.  Anti-aliasing cannot work without a known background and pixel grid fitting is too ugly at current monitor resolutions.

Comment: Rolling your own controls is almost always a bad idea as the required effort is often underestimated. Workaround if the background of the controls doesn't have to be translucent: Create a regular, non-modal, borderless dialog that is owned by the layered window and synchronize its position with the layered window. The borderless dialog can use all Win32 controls. If background of controls has to be translucent, look into more modern GUI technologies like WPF or WinUI 3.

Comment: @zett42 "*Layered windows are not compatible with standard Win32 controls*" - that is only true when using `UpdateLayeredWindow()` to draw the window. But that is not true when using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()`, which allows for traditional `WM_PAINT` handling.